# POJO Matches table but I get a Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type Exception

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

The query I wrote by hand works in the H2 console:

[image]

But when I add the query to the JPA Repository I get this exception, I thought since the result set and the property names and data types lined up it would be able to map it automatically?

> Exception Message: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object[]] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.apex.eqp.inventory.entities.Product] for value '{2, Ford F150, 2990.0, 10}'

**Product.java**

> 

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;

    private double price;

    private Integer quantity;

}
```

**RecalledProduct.java**

> 

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RecalledProduct {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;
}
```

**InventoryRepository.java**

> 

```
@Repository
public interface InventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT p.id AS id, p.name AS name, p.price AS price, p.quantity AS quantity " +
            "FROM Product p " +
            "LEFT JOIN RecalledProduct rp ON p.name = rp.name " +
            "WHERE rp.name IS NULL")
    List<Product> getAllNotRecalledProducts();

}
```

**Stack Trace**

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.apex.eqp.inventory.entities.Product]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToObjectConverter.convert(ArrayToObjectConverter.java:68) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToCollectionConverter.convert(CollectionToCollectionConverter.java:89) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:213) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutionResultHandler.postProcessInvocationResult(QueryExecutionResultHandler.java:167) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutionResultHandler.postProcessInvocationResult(QueryExecutionResultHandler.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy87.getAllNotRecalledProducts(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at com.apex.eqp.inventory.services.ProductService.getAllNotRecalledProduct(ProductService.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.apex.eqp.inventory.controllers.InventoryController.getAllNotRecalledProducts(InventoryController.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]

**What Did I expect?**

For the result set to be mapped to the return type of the Repository method automatically.

Comment: The out of the box JPA methods return results so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried adding `@Column` annotations to the `price` and `quantity` fields?  If the all args constructor exists, I don't think that's necessary, but it's something I would try just to get a bearing.

Comment: @CryptoFool Just tried, same result. I wonder if the result set is in a different data type under the hood or if the names are different? That is why I added the AS to the query thinking they names were changes somehow.

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be the answer to your problem, but your use of JOIN seems strange to me.  You are matching the 'name' column in two tables, but only if the value of 'name' in the second table is NONE.  I don't see how that would ever make sense.  Still, it shouldn't affect what columns are returned or how they are mapped to a POJO.  Can't you lose the JOIN and just test for `p.name is NONE`?

Comment: Yea basically instead of having a isRecalled column on the products table, i was given these two tables where if the product name from the product table appears on the product_recall table then the product is recalled. I want to retrieve all products that are not recalled. Trying to do this in single query instead of making two calls and filtering in Java.